# How to deal with n+1 when find name by id with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 4.2

## Model

app/models/product.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
# id
# name
# 

class Product < ActiveRecord
  has_many :product_items, foreign_key: :product_id, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_items
end
```

app/models/product_item.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: product_items
#
# id
# product_id
# note_id
# description
# 

class ProductItem < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :note
end
```

app/models/note.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: notes
#
# id
# name
# 

class Note < ActiveRecord
  has_many :product_items, foreign_key: :note_id
end
```

## Controller

app/controllers/products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # Something

  def show
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id]).includes(:product_items)
  end
end
```

## View

app/views/products/show.html.erb

```
<% if @product.product_items.present? %>
  <% @product.product_items.each do |item| %>
    <div><%= item.note.name %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then I saw this notice:

```
N+1 Query detected ProductItem => [:note] Add to your finder: :includes => [:note]
```

---

I want to show note name at the note_id place of product_items. I have tried to add a scope in the `ProductItem` model:

```
scope, :note, -> { includes(:notes) }
```

But the result was the same. How to includes notes from product_items correctly?

---

## Edit

I have tried these methods by @PrakashLaxkar and @blushrt :

```
Product.includes(:product_items => :note).find(params[:id])
Product.joins(:product_items => :note).find(params[:id])
```

But it also query many times:

```
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.812837 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.818248 #16844] DEBUG -- :   ProductItem Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `product_items`.* FROM `product_items` WHERE `product_items`.`product_id` = 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.820713 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` = 36 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.823019 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` = 35 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.824233 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` = 39 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.826517 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` = 42 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.830015 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` = 28 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.834301 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` = 11 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.837405 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` = 12 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:16:53.840325 #16844] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` = 50 LIMIT 1
```

---

## Edit 2

(Try another way)

After I rewrite my view as:

```
<% @product.product_items.includes(:note).each do |item| %>
```

It works fine:

```
D, [2015-09-17T11:29:50.280367 #18842] DEBUG -- :   Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:29:50.315951 #18842] DEBUG -- :   ProductItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `product_items`.* FROM `product_items` WHERE `product_items`.`product_id` = 1
D, [2015-09-17T11:29:50.323917 #18842] DEBUG -- :   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `product_items`.* FROM `product_items` WHERE `product_items`.`product_id` = 1  [["product_id", 1]]
D, [2015-09-17T11:29:50.349202 #18842] DEBUG -- :   Note Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` IN (36, 35, 39, 42, 28, 11, 12, 50)
```

It means that it need a association in the model. So I tried:

```
# app/models/product_item.rb
scope :note_info, -> { includes(:note) }

# app/views/products/show.html.erb
<% @product.product_items.note_info.each do |item| %>
```

It works fine, too.

---

## Edit 3

(Answer to @blushrt)

After I tried it in my rails console:

```
$ rails c
[2] pry(main)> product = Product.includes(:product_items => :note).find(1)                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ProductItem Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `product_items`.* FROM `product_items` WHERE `product_items`.`product_id` IN (1)
  Note Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`id` IN (36, 35, 39, 42, 28, 11, 12, 50)
+----+------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| id | name | created_at                | updated_at                |
+----+------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| 1  | food | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 18:52:48 +0900 |
+----+------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
1 row in set
[3] pry(main)> product.product_items.each do |item|
[3] pry(main)*   item.note.name
[3] pry(main)* end
+----+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| id | product_id | note_id | description | created_at                | updated_at                |
+----+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| 1  | 1              | 36                | good     | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 |
| 2  | 1              | 35                | worse    | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 |
| 3  | 1              | 39                | worse    | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 |
| 4  | 1              | 42                | worse    | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 |
| 5  | 1              | 28                | worse    | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 |
| 6  | 1              | 11                | worse    | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 19:10:13 +0900 |
| 7  | 1              | 12                | worse    | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 |
| 8  | 1              | 50                | worse    | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 | 2015-09-16 17:51:12 +0900 |
+----+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
8 rows in set
```

The first time indeed has three queries, but it query many times when I show note data in the view.

Comment: A scope is not an association, what you are doing here is overriding association named "note". It's not necessary.  All you have to do is eager load all 3 associations like I've written and then each item.note call won't fire another query..

Comment: If it works in console, it should work in your view the same. Can I see a server log of you visiting the product show page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this on the controller?

```
@product = Product.includes(:product_items).find(params[:id])

if @product.product_items.present?
  @product_items = @product.product_items.includes(:notes)
end
```

and in the view

```
<% @product_items.each do |item| %>
  <div><%= item.note.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

This will avoid the N+1, and solve this in 3 queries

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Product.includes(:product_items => :note).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thank you. The result was the same.

Comment: Are you sure ? Originally I posted .includes([:product_items, :note]) which is wrong. This one should do it.

Comment: Yes. I did that, but after I reloaded my browser, I found it also query for notes for many a time by note_id from product_items.

Comment: Try running my line in rails console, you should see 3 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work for you

```
Product.includes(:product_items => :note).find(params[:id])
```

If you want that each product item must contain note name then try joins instead of includes as

```
Product.joins(:product_items => :note).find(params[:id])
```

It will return product only which have item and note associated. Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't execute separate quires. Remove your scope which you added for note and try again. Thanks

Comment: I can't remove my scope, but modified it. See my `Edit 2`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @s-cho-m remove the scope because you are overriding the relation name of belongs_to.  product_item.note should have a single Note right ?

Comment: Then in your view just do <%@product.product_items.each...%><%= item.note %> When you call item.note it should not make another query because you are already eager loading it with includes. It's cached in memory. And btw join is not saved in memmory.

Comment: @blushrt Thank you. See my `Edit 3`. I pasted my test in rails console.